# Query regarding url of mfpdev server

Tags: mobilefirst-bluemix

I am creating mfpdev server, so it's asking for fully qualified url from me. And I have tried several url and its port but non of them work

URL that I tried are:-

https://mybluemixserver.mybluemix.net:9080

It's giving me an error:

> Cannot connect to server 'MyBluemixSrver' at 'https://mybluemixserver.mybluemix.net:9080'.
>   Missing runtime configuration details.: The HTTP request has timed out.

I have tried several queries for that but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use port 9080 with HTTPS...
It's either HTTP with port 9080 or HTTPS with port 443.

I guess you're referring to adding a server profile in the MobileFirst CLI. There's documentation to help you.

- `mfpdev help server`
- [Documentation topic](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#managing-mobilefirst-server-instances)

Example:

```
$ mfpdev server add
? Enter the name of the new server profile: MyBluemixServer
? Enter the fully qualified URL of this server: https://mobilefoundation-7abcd-server.mybluemix.net:443
? Enter the MobileFirst Server administrator login ID: admin
? Enter the MobileFirst Server administrator password: *****
? Save the administrator password for this server?: Yes
? Enter the context root of the MobileFirst administration services: mfpadmin
? Enter the MobileFirst Server connection timeout in seconds: 30
? Make this server the default?: Yes
Verifying server configuration...
The following runtimes are currently installed on this server: mfp
Server profile 'MyBluemixServer' added successfully.
```

Comment: i have created an instance of mobile foundation service in bluemix can i use  it's server route for my fully qualified URL

Comment: "fully qualified URL" for **what purpose**.  Simply follow the example.